# Using pandas, how can I compare the values between 2 columns from two dataframes and push them to a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I'm new to Python and I'm trying to use Pandas to make a new dataframe using values from two existing ones. Basically using these dataframes:

`df1=
    A    B
a  '1'  '3'
b  '4'  '3'
c  '3'  '2'
d  '9'  '1'`

`df2=
    C    D
a  '5'  '1'
b  '2'  '0'
c  '4'  '2'
d  '1'  '9'`

I need to create a loop that will compare the value of each line in df1[A] to the value of each line df2[C]. If the values are equal, I need to join df1[A, B] and df2[C] and push that line to a third dataframe. So the result should look like this for the examples above:

`dfnew=
    A    B    D
a  '1'  '3'  '9'
b  '4'  '3'  '2'`

Since not all the values I'm working with will be integers I also need to treat the values as strings.

I've been checking out other similar questions but none of the answers seem to get me exactly what I need done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with default `inner join` and [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='A', right_on='C').drop('C', axis=1)
```

Another solution with `rename` column for join:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2.rename(columns={'C':'A'}), on='A')

print (df)
     A    B    D
0  '1'  '3'  '9'
1  '4'  '3'  '2'
```

***Notice:***

*Values in joined columns has to be unique.*

Comment: That first one works perfectly! Thanks so much! Out of curiosity, do you know if I can use .drop to just drop any rows where B < D? I kinda forgot to add that part to my question...

Comment: Super. `.drop('C', axis=1)` delete only column `C`

Comment: So the easiest is define columns in list for remove like - `.drop(['C', 'E', 'F'], axis=1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pd.Series.map`

```
df1.assign(D=df1.A.map(dict(zip(df2.C, df2.D)))).dropna()

     A    B    D
a  '1'  '3'  '9'
b  '4'  '3'  '2'
```

---

**Details**
With just the `map` and `assign` we are left with rows that we need to drop.

```
df1.assign(D=df1.A.map(df2.set_index('C').D))

     A    B    D
a  '1'  '3'  '9'
b  '4'  '3'  '2'
c  '3'  '2'  NaN
d  '9'  '1'  NaN
```

I decided to drop them with a simple `dropna`.  To be more precise, we probably should restrict the `dropna` to the `D` column.

```
df1.assign(D=df1.A.map(df2.set_index('C').D)).dropna(subset=['D'])

     A    B    D
a  '1'  '3'  '9'
b  '4'  '3'  '2'
```

We could use other ways as well.  But then that wasn't really what this question was about.